# MySQL Select DISTINCT column1, column2From Table order by colum2 DESC

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with writing this query by the following features:

1. First order by column2 DESC and then choose from Distinct column1
2. Only Column1 is DISTINCT

This query doesn't help since it first choose from column1 and then order by Column2

```
Select Column1, Column2 From Table
Group By Column1
Order By Column2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the first value of `column2` for each `column1`?  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select column1, max(column2)
from table
group by column1
order by min(column2) desc;
```

Comment: @nazanin . . . Yes, that is what `desc` would do.  I fixed it.

Comment: if I add one column (column3) to this, it doesn't return right answer! since it first do grouping and then do order. Now what should I do?